# NGINX and Apache port 80 conflict

Tags: django, apache

I am running a DigitalOcean droplet that is running a wordpress instillation on apache. I am trying to get a NGINX and Django system up and running but it's not allowing me to use port 80 as it's already in use.

Heres my command that runs Django:

```
gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectName.settings --settings projectName.settings -b domainName.co.uk projectName.wsgi
```

Heres my file contents at: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/projectName`

```
server {
        server_name domainName.co.uk

        access_log off;

        location /static/ {
                alias /opt/projectName/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
}
```

When I visit the domain name, it's just showing me the website for the default droplet (the WP instillation). I'm guessing the proxy_pass is where the data should be going but it's not.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please. Thankyou

*Edit*

I have ended up going down the Apache route and i've now got this in my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file. Should the IP be 127.0.0.1?

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8001/

    ServerName domainName.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in trying to run both nginx and Apache.

All nginx is doing in this situation is acting as a reverse proxy for gunicorn. Since you're already running Apache for your Wordpress site, you should configure it to handle the Django site too; either using mod_proxy to make it work as a reverse proxy like nginx, or (probably preferably) handling the Django site directly via mod_wsgi.

Comment: Any guides on setting up Apache as a reverse proxy?

Comment: I've never done it, but there's a DO tutorial on it here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension. Seems like you mainly need to activate mod_proxy then set the `ProxyPass` and `ReverseProxyPass` directives.

Comment: I have made changes to my original question with the new apache code

Comment: Not sure what your question is now. What are you seeing?

Comment: It's just showing the original wordpress on the droplet still